# Unable to create nested expandable rows with checkboxes and data using angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

here i am trying to create a nested expandable table from flat json

what i did :

below is flat json :

```
           public unsortedData = [
  {
    "url": "3452188c-a156-4ee4-b6f9-9d313bdbb148",
    "_id": "3452188c-a156-4ee4-b6f9-9d313bdbb148",
    "part": "wing",
    "main": "boeing",
    "part_id": "3452188c-a156-4ee4-b6f9-9d313bdbb148",
    "information.data_check": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6"
  },
  {
    "url": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6",
    "_id": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6",
    "part": "wing",
    "main": "boeing",
    "part_id": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6",
    "information.data_check": "parent_info"
  },
  {
    "url": "3b42eeee-c7e3-4d75-953e-941351b4e0f9",
    "_id": "3b42eeee-c7e3-4d75-953e-941351b4e0f9",
    "part": "wing",
    "main": "boeing",
    "part_id": "3b42eeee-c7e3-4d75-953e-941351b4e0f9",
    "information.data_check": "single_info"
  }
];
```

and converted it to the nested json like below :

```
[
  {
    "nested": [
      {
        "url": "3452188c-a156-4ee4-b6f9-9d313bdbb148",
        "_id": "3452188c-a156-4ee4-b6f9-9d313bdbb148",
        "part": "wing",
        "main": "boeing",
        "part_id": "3452188c-a156-4ee4-b6f9-9d313bdbb148",
        "information.data_check": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6"
      }
    ],
    "url": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6",
    "_id": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6",
    "part": "wing",
    "main": "boeing",
    "part_id": "ad1bd2a7-710d-88aa-6da0-8de2140417c6",
    "information.data_check": "parent_info"
  },
  {
    "url": "3b42eeee-c7e3-4d75-953e-941351b4e0f9",
    "_id": "3b42eeee-c7e3-4d75-953e-941351b4e0f9",
    "part": "wing",
    "main": "boeing",
    "part_id": "3b42eeee-c7e3-4d75-953e-941351b4e0f9",
    "information.data_check": "single_info"
  }
]
```

and it came like below

[image: Nested data]

**Issue:** 
 1.  In the expandable rows the parent data is again repeated instead of displaying the child (which is there in under nested).

2. Although implemented checkbox selection for all rows but it has been effected for only for parent not to the child so need to select all the rows in the table and get their ids

Im not sure what is causing the issue below is my stackblitz:--> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsdvgd

Comment: Your issues are not clear. Please List them.

Comment: @PrathapG please check the updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue1**
you had to use nested  in children

```
{{nested[key]}}
```

instead of

```
{{element[key]}}
```

**Issure 2**
It works just fine. look at his stackblitz. It marks both children and parents.

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmxvja

**EDIT**

since I saw second answer. I realized you might need to have checkboxes in children rows.

to do so add:

```
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(nested) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(nested)"
            [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(nested)">
            </mat-checkbox>
```

in nested div.

the result is like this. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb7adw

[image]

**Edit 2:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8fv2vk
from what I understood this is what you want.
now only ids are added in selection.
children checkbox is selected on parent click now.

heres the image from result:[image]

there is one single problem. adding this many checkboxes increases complexity of checking unchecking logic.

```
  selectSingle(event, row) {
    row.nested.forEach(nestedRow => {
      if (!this.selection.isSelected(row._id)) {
        if (!this.selection.isSelected(row._id)) {
          this.selection.select(nestedRow._id);
        } else {
          this.selection.select(nestedRow._id);
        }
      } else {
        if (!this.selection.isSelected(row._id)) {
          this.selection.select(nestedRow._id);
        } else {

        }
      }
    })
    this.selection.isSelected(row._id)
    return event ? this.selection.toggle(row._id) : null
  }
```

this is the function that decides that logic on parent click. you can twick it the way you prefer. I am not sure what logic you prefer. I put the one that sounds best from what you asked in you questions.

[image]
all expanded shows all of them are marked.

to get rid of hiphen.

change code from:

```
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
         [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
```

to

```
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
         [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
```

but I'm not sure if its worth it. this might or might not break something else.

Comment: the approach is nice but i have some issue with that

Comment: did you check both stackblitzes? let me know what issues you have.

Comment: i checked it the issue  1. When we are selecting the parent why not the children are being selected . and what if we want only child to be selected and we dont want parent to be selected  2. how  can i get the only ids upon selection

Comment: perfect it is working i see a small issue when we do a select all it is not ticking instead showing -

Comment: it ticks all of the boxes for me. make sure you are looking at last stackblitz unedited.

Comment: on the header if u select all then you can see

Comment: I added image. this is how it works for me. I might be misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: if u see the top most header id  when all the rows are checked instead tick it showing  hiphen

Comment: hiphen means deselect. that's how its supposed to work. but to take it off get rid off [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()" in <th> <mat header>

Comment: @Vato can you pls help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71267560/select-all-checkboxes-by-default-in-nested-mat-table-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution for your issues

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtupwz

1.You have to create a new method in the ts file to retrieve the value. You are retrieving the key, instead of the value

app.component.ts

```
    getKeysTop(object): string[] {
       console.log(Object.keys(object));
       return Object.values(object);
    }
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="example-element-description__cell" *ngFor="let value of getKeysTop(nested)" style="padding-left: -5px;">{{value}}</div>
```

2.You have to repeat the checkbox code block for the nested row

app.component.html

```
                 <div class="example-element-description">
                  <div class="example-element-description__header">
                    <div class="example-element-description__cell" *ngFor="let key of getKeys(element['nested'][0])">{{key}}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngFor="let nested of element['nested']; let idx = index"    
                      class="example-element-description__content"
                      (click)=onItemSelected(idx)>
                     
                    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                    
                <div class="example-element-description__cell" *ngFor="let value of getKeysTop(nested)" style="padding-left: -5px;">{{value}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: here in your approach we are not selecting all rows i guess including the child